# ValueError: Unable to restore custom object of type _tf_keras_metric

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, azure-databricks, mlflow

I am new to databricks and mlflow and I trained a model in a Databricks cluster with tensorflow like this:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import LearningRateScheduler
from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.regularizers import l2
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import Precision, Recall
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, LabelEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pandas as pd


def scheduler(epoch, lr):
  if epoch < 360:
    return lr
  if epoch >360 and epoch <380:
    return lr * 0.5
  else:
    return 0.0001

precision = Precision()
recall = Recall()

def f1_score(y_true, y_pred):
    p = precision(y_true, y_pred)
    r = recall(y_true, y_pred)
    return 2 * ((p * r) / (p + r + 1e-5))

# Separate the features and target
# simulate some data
d = {'target': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1], 'feature': [10, 20, 30, 10, 20, 30, 10, 20, 30, 10]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
X = df.drop(columns=['target'])
y = df['target']

# Encode the target variable
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
y_encoded = label_encoder.fit_transform(y)
y_onehot = to_categorical(y_encoded)

# Split the data into training and test sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y_onehot, test_size=0.1, random_state=42)

# Scale the features
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_scaled = scaler.transform(X_test)

# Define the deep neural network model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1024, input_shape=(X_train_scaled.shape[1],), activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(y_onehot.shape[1], activation='softmax'))

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy',  f1_score])

# ModelCheckpoint callback to save best model based on validation F1 score
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('best_model_test.h5', monitor='val_f1_score', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')

callbacks = [LearningRateScheduler(scheduler), checkpoint]

history_1 = model.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train, epochs=400, batch_size=128, validation_data=(X_test_scaled, y_test), callbacks=callbacks)
```

It appears in the experiments tab and i am tying to load it with mlflow with the exact code that is presented there:

```
import mlflow
logged_model = 'runs:/6db172cf2c0247bb8393287a63e50b20/model'

# Load model as a PyFuncModel.
loaded_model = mlflow.pyfunc.load_model(logged_model)
```

My problem is that i have this error:

```
ValueError: Unable to restore custom object of type _tf_keras_metric. Please make sure that any custom layers are included in the `custom_objects` arg when calling `load_model()` and make sure that all layers implement `get_config` and `from_config`.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
File <command-1950128807397632>:5
      2 logged_model = 'runs:/6db172cf2c0247bb8393287a63e50b20/model'
      4 # Load model as a PyFuncModel.
----> 5 loaded_model = mlflow.pyfunc.load_model(logged_model)

File /databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mlflow/pyfunc/__init__.py:597, in load_model(model_uri, suppress_warnings, dst_path)
    595 _add_code_from_conf_to_system_path(local_path, conf, code_key=CODE)
    596 data_path = os.path.join(local_path, conf[DATA]) if (DATA in conf) else local_path
--> 597 model_impl = importlib.import_module(conf[MAIN])._load_pyfunc(data_path)
    598 predict_fn = conf.get("predict_fn", "predict")
    599 return PyFuncModel(model_meta=model_meta, model_impl=model_impl, predict_fn=predict_fn)

File /databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mlflow/tensorflow/__init__.py:741, in _load_pyfunc(path)
    739 if K.backend() == "tensorflow":
    740     K.set_learning_phase(0)
--> 741     m = _load_keras_model(
    742         path, keras_module=keras_module, save_format=save_format, compile=should_compile
    743     )
    744     return _KerasModelWrapper(m, model_meta.signature)
```

I tried to define the f1 metric but pyfunc does not recognize 'custom_objects' as a function parameter.

The custom_objects argument is not directly supported by the pyfunc.load_model() function in MLflow. This argument is typically used with Keras' load_model() function to load models with custom objects.
And I am stuck here, how can I load the model from mlflow?